# Difference Between DBA and All privileges

Tags: oracle

I want to know what is the difference between the following two statements in oracle:

1. `GRANT DBA TO Jack`
2. `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO Jack`

Comment: Is this not documented? [Oracle 12.1 SQL Language Reference: GRANT](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9013.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I advise you not to try providing dba and ***NEVER*** provide ALL PRIVILEDGES to any user, because such thing should be done only by experienced developers.
Usually there is only ***ONE*** user who is provided DBA role.

As per oracle documentation:
When oracle database is installed, there are two admin roles created:
1. SYS  2. SYSTEM

An ***SYS*** role can access internal data dictionary tables of oracle database.
All of the base tables and views for the database data dictionary are stored in the schema SYS. These base tables and views are critical for the operation of Oracle Database. To maintain the integrity of the data dictionary, tables in the SYS schema are manipulated only by the database.

***If you flirted with any internal sys tables, you may face license cancellation***

The ***SYSTEM*** username is used to create additional tables and views that display administrative information, and internal tables and views used by various Oracle Database options and tools. Never use the SYSTEM schema to store tables of interest to non-administrative users.

The DBA role does not include the SYSDBA or SYSOPER system privileges. These are special administrative privileges that allow an administrator to perform basic database administration tasks, such as creating the database and instance startup and shutdown.

Here GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES are provided to user on particular object, even system object, and this does not includes sys and system privilege, you can do any action on such object, this is why you should avoid using ALL PRIVILEGES.